# push key value to jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I added recently a jsonb field to one of my tables

```
add_column :users, :preferences, :jsonb, null: false, default: '{}'
```

and I am storing values like this :

```
user = User.first
user.preferences = { job: "programmer" }
```

now I would like to push another key-value pair to my jsonb field, I tried this in the console :

```
user = User.first
user.preferences.merge(twitter_account: "something")
user.save
```

and I get something like

```
....
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

which normally means it's saved !  but when I check the value of `preferences` I don't see any added value, even when I exit the console and re-run rails console again, I can see any change

Is that the way to do it or I am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [merge](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge) it return hash with added values but to add values to hash you need to use [merge!](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!)

I think that right way will be

```
user.preferences = user.preferences.merge(twitter_account: "something")
```

Comment: Yes I see that jsonb is used here similar to normal hash, I can also do `user.preferences["twitter_account"] = "something_else"`  thanks!